# Is it possible to sell other application by in app purchase

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am developing an library application for ios.
Is it possible to make our books as an application and sell them by In-App Purchase.

If so, how can i install a downloaded app and open it from my main library application.
and how return to main library application from books.

Comment: Look into how games distribute and authenticate DLCs and you've found the answer to what you wanna do. Essentially, you won't be selling an app, but a right and priviledge to access/download a file from your server.

Answer (score 1):

If your books are applications, in your library app you can use `SKStoreProductViewController` to display your other apps and allow them to be purchased and installed. This isn't an in-app purchase but it does achieve your goal.

---

From your comments you don't actually want to use apps (or sell apps). You can have interaction and animation in your books without them being apps. How you sell them is dependent upon what they are. I'd use in-app purchase and construct each book as a pack of information that you can decode / unpack and describes what interaction is possible and includes any resources you need. This could be like a zip file you download.

Comment: I want to use a custom View Controller in my library app to show the books however i want (something like Playtails).

Comment: Does that app just display books to be loaded and viewed in the current app or actually as separate apps?

Comment: [This](http://i.imgbox.com/abtl8Mq9.jpg) is how i want to show book in my library. when user tap on a book, the app show book's details in a popup view and user can buy the book. purchased books will be shown in another part of the application and user can open and watch(read) them.

Comment: So the books aren't apps, they're just content. You can use a basic in-app purchase for that and have Apple host the content, or have it in the app already and just enable access, or download it from your own server.

Comment: Book in our application should be interactive and have animation, sound , ... . So i want to make them as application. is there any way to implement such thing with in app purchase? or i am going the wrong way!